# tem como pegar valor de uma coluna pelo $_GET sem ser passado na URL?

Tags: php

oque eu quero fazer e um sisteminha de noticias relacionadas, por enquanto tenho isso

**home.php**

```
$noticias=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `noticias` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

if(isset($nomeNoticia)||isset($slug)){

    $noticias->bindValue(":nomeNoticia",$nomeNoticia,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $noticias->bindValue(":slug",$slug,PDO::PARAM_STR);

}

$noticias->execute();

$row=$noticias->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($row as $listar){

    $nome=$listar->nomeNoticia;
    $slug=$listar->slug;

    echo '<a href="'.$urlBase.'/noticia/'.$slug.'">'.$nome.'</a>';

}
```

**verNoticia.php**

```
$verNoticia=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `noticias` WHERE `slug` = '$post'");

if(isset($nomeNoticia)||isset($relacao)){

    $verNoticia->bindValue(":nomeNoticia",$nomeNoticia,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $verNoticia->bindValue(":relacao",$relacao,PDO::PARAM_STR);

}

$infoEpisodio->execute();
$rowVNoticia=$verNoticia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($rowVNoticia as $listarNoticia){
    $nome=$listarNoticia->nomeNoticia;
    //unico jeito que pego a coluna relacao
    $relacao=$listarNoticia->relacao;

    echo '

         Nome: '.$nomeNoticia.'
         Categoria: '.$relacao.'

    ';

}
```

**oque eu tentei**

```
//pensei que o $_GET pegaria os valores da coluna relacao que eu imprimo acima
if(isset($relacao)){
   $relacao = $_GET['relacao'];
}
$relacionadas=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(relacao) AS Relacao FROM `noticias` WHERE `relacao` LIKE '$relacao%'");
```

isso deu variavel indefinida na query `Undefined variable: relacao`

o objetivo disso e so mostrar as noticias que a coluna `relacao` seja identica

exemplo

`Noticia 07 coluna relacao = aventura, esportes`

`Noticia 03 coluna relacao = aventura, esportes`

`Noticia 10 coluna relacao = aventura, esportes`

`Noticia 25 coluna relacao = aventura, esportes`

Comment: Como assim passar pela URL? O get só pega o que está na URL, talvez esteja confundindo com o `$_POST`

Comment: @MarceloBoni eu preciso recuperar o valor da coluna relacao, sem listar ela e sem passar pela url, ou seja o codigo tem que verificar quais registros tem os mesmos nomes no campo relacao, e trazer so os mesmos, entendeu ? pra ser mais claro, e um sisteminha de relacionados, exemplo Noticia 01 ->categoria esportes, aventura, ai traz as outras noticias que a coluna relacao seja esportes, aventuras

Comment: Desculpe, não posso te ajudar no chat. Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e tentar seu o mais claro possível sobre o que você está tentando fazer (não sobre como você *acha* que deve ser a solução!)

Comment: @bfavaretto oque eu quero fazer e muito simples, quero fazer um sisteminha de noticias relacionadas, exemplo, tenho a Noticia 01, essa noticia 01 tem a categoria de esporte, aventura, ai o cara clica nela, abre ela inteira pra ler, ai aparece as outras noticias relacionadas, exemplo, Noticia 05 tem a categoria esporte, aventura Noticia 10 tem a categoria esporte, aventura, ou seja so mostra as que sao relacionadas, onde a coluna `relacao` seja identica a todas, entendeu ?

Comment: Entendi. Então você já acessa seu banco de dados e já recebe os dados da notícia ali, certo? O título, o texto, etc. A categoria não vem junto? Se vem, é daí que você tem que pegar. Senão, você puxa do banco com base no código da notícia atual. Sugiro, de novo, [edit] a pergunta tentando explicar o problema em detalhes e de onde você está partindo. Capaz até que no caminho você consiga resolver sozinho.

Comment: Você já consegue mostrar as categorias da notícia na página? Se sim, já tem o valor que precisa para usar na sua query!

Comment: @bfavaretto sim eu mostro o valor das categorias, isso que eu queria saber, como identificar esses valores na minha query

Comment: Você precisa mostrar etapa por etapa na pergunta ..por exemplo... Na minha opinião... Assim: Quando o usuário clica na notícia a url fica assim: (url) e então eu busco no banco a noticia assim:(codigo de busca) e então eu tenho isso... e depois isso... mas não consigo fazer isso...

Comment: Você precisa detalhar melhor

Comment: @AndreiCoelho editei a pergunta

Comment: Você já tem `$relacao=$listarNoticia->relacao;` num dos arquivos. Não é disso que você precisa?

Comment: @bfavaretto consegui, na verdade estava tudo certo, oque nao estava dando certo, era que no ao cadastrar a categoria no banco eu removi todos os acentos, e na listagem eu coloquei os acentos, ai a consulta nao tava reconhecendo, oque eu fiz foi deixar uma coluna com acentos e outra sem acentos, assim deu certo